# Packet rate of Velodyne HDL-64E in velodyne_driver

Tags: ros, velodyne-driver, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,

I am trying to understand the velodyne_driver code where I found the following:

```
// get model name, validate string, determine packet rate
private_nh.param("model", config_.model, std::string("64E"));
double packet_rate;                   // packet frequency (Hz)
if (config_.model == "64E")
  {
    packet_rate = 2600.0;
  }
else if (config_.model == "32E")
  {
    packet_rate = 1808.0;
  }
else
  {
    ROS_ERROR_STREAM("unknown Velodyne LIDAR model: " << config_.model);
    packet_rate = 2600.0;
  }
```

I did not know why the packet rate is 2600 so I checked the Velodyne HDL-64E manual and it writes:

> **Data Packet Construction**
>
> The HDL-64E S2 outputs UDP Ethernet
> packets. Each packet contains a data
> payload of 1206 bytes that consists of
> 12 blocks of 100-byte firing data
> followed by six bytes at the end of
> each packet that contains a spin
> counter and firmware version
> information. Each packet can be for
> either the upper or lower laser banks
> (called “laser blocks”) - each bank
> contains 32 lasers.
>
> The packet format is as follows:
>
> - **2 bytes of header info.** This header indicates whether the packet is
>   for the upper block or the lower
>   block. The upper block will have a
>   header of 0xEEFF and the lower block
>   will have a header of 0xDDFF.
> - **2 bytes of rotational info.** This is an integer between 0 and
>
> 35999. Divide this number by 100 to get degrees from 0.
>
> - **32 laser returns broken into 3 bytes each.** Each return contains two
>   bytes of distance information in .2
>   centimeter [2mm] increments, and one
>   byte of intensity information (0 –
>   255, with 255 being the most intense
>   return). A zero distance value within
>   the data packet indicates there are no
>   returns up to 120 meters, the maximum
>   range of the device.

This:

> The HDL-64E S2 can spin at rates ranging from 300 RPM (5 Hz) to 900 RPM (15 Hz). The
> default is 600 RPM (10 Hz). Note that changing the spin rate does not change the data
> rate - the unit will send out the same number of packets (at a rate of 1.3 million
> data points per second) regardless of spin rate. The image resolution will increase
> or decrease depending on rotation speed.

And also this:

> 20,833 points per second, per laser x 64 = 1,333,312 total points per second
> therefore, the HDL-64E S2 generates greater than 1.3 million points per second.

So, according the the manual:

- Each packet contains a data payload of 1206 bytes that consists of 12 blocks of 100-byte firing data
- Each firing data contains 32 laser returns
- In 1 second the device generates 1 333 312 points.

It means 1 packet contains 384 laser returns therefore the packet rate should be about 3472.

Do I misunderstand something?

**Update:** Thanks joq! I read both the 64E and the 64E S2 manuals and you are right, they generate different number of point per second. The 64E one generates 1 000 000 points per second meanwhile the 64E S2 generates the mentioned 1 333 312 points per second.

In case of 64E's 1 000 000 points the calculated packet rate is 2604.16 which is almost what you measured.

I checked the 64E S2's 3472.16 packet rate with our device data and it works well.

If you do not mind I would like to create the patch. I am new in ROS and github and I would like to practice.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67320/packet-rate-of-velodyne-hdl-64e-in-velodyne_driver/) by [Gabor Meszaros](https://answers.ros.org/users/2093/gabor-meszaros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2013-07-14

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-07-17**:
Thanks for the bug report, I created a github issue for it: https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/issues/11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The 64E rate is an experimental result with our non-S2 device. I don't have access to an S2. Can you confirm the numbers above with it? If necessary we can add another model designation for the S2.

**Update**: a patch would be great. I think it'll be straightforward, so you can concentrate on the github mechanics. Just ask, if you need help.

The only other 64E S2 user I've heard from was a couple of years ago. He provided a patch for his angles configuration extensions. Since you have access to an S2, we should set up a unit test of some kind. Perhaps you can supply the angles configuration for your device. The `velodyne_pointcloud/params/utexas_64e.yaml` is for our older, non-S2 device.

**Update2**: for anyone using an earlier version of the driver without this fix, here is a work-around for the 64E S2 or S2.1:

```
$ rosrun velodyne_driver velodyne_node _npackets:=384 _rpm:=600
```

**EDIT:** corrected npackets typo (was 348)

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gabor Meszaros](https://answers.ros.org/users/2093/gabor-meszaros/) on 2013-07-17**:
Sure, I can give it to you. I have a question about the patch, but I will ask it on the issue's github page. Thank you!

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-07-18**:
Good. To keep this from breaking again in the future I'd like a short (~20MB) PCAP dump file from your device. That way I can create a unit test like the existing ones for 32E and our old 64E.

**Comment by [pengpeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/26541/pengpeng/) on 2016-05-09**:
I find the same quesiton in Velodyne HDL32-E，the horizontal resolution is 0.16 degree,so the package rate is 1875, but I want to know  where can I modify the paramter, I have install the driver,Shoud I change the code,then catkin_make by myself?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-05-09**:
The [current master uses 1808 for the 32e](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/blob/master/velodyne_driver/src/driver/driver.cc#L53) packet rate. If you believe that is wrong, please open an issue. We can discuss it there.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-05-09**:
You can override the packet rate by explicitly setting the `npackets` parameter to whatever you like.

**Comment by [pengpeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/26541/pengpeng/) on 2016-05-09**:
Thank you for your reply,I change the npackets to 1875,But I still can't get a circle,some sectors still had't data,moreover,I compared with the data from the veloview ,I found it had some difference,Can you tell me why

**Comment by [teddyort](https://answers.ros.org/users/26358/teddyort/) on 2016-12-06**:
@joq I believe there is a small typo in your workaround

`rosrun velodyne_driver velodyne_node _npackets:=348 _rpm:=600`

should read

`rosrun velodyne_driver velodyne_node _npackets:=384 _rpm:=600`

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-12-06**:
Thanks! So, noted.